# Are there any sites here that talk about financing?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I have a question about credit cards and credit lines, but I wasn't able to find a site devoted to such topics.

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/ should be fine there, they have a few generic credit questions https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credit-card

Answer (score 4):

[Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/) deals with these kind of topics. I see you have already [posted your question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/91606/27340) there, good luck with it.

As always, before posting a question on a new site, be sure to read their Help Center; [What topics can I ask about here?](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are good places to start.